# Converse statement to the definition of the Chi-squared distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Definition of the Chi-squared distribution (in most of the textbooks) is the following:

If $Z_1,\ldots,Z_k$ are independent standard normal random variables then distribution of the sum of their squares is called the Chi-squared distribution: 
$\sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^2 \sim \chi^2(k).$

But what about the converse statement?

Let $X \sim \chi^2(k)$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Does it imply that there exists independent standard normal random variables $Z_1, \ldots, Z_k$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ such that $X = \sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^2$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily on $({\mit Ω}, \mathscr{F}, P)$. It should be that there're $Z_1, \cdots, Z_n$ i.i.d. on $({\mit Ω}', \mathscr{F'}, P')$ and $Z_k \sim N(0, 1)$ such that $X \stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n Z_k^2$.

Comment: I suspect that you could find the conditional distribution of $Z_k$ given $\sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^2 = s_k$.  If you took a value from this $z_k$, and let $s_{k-1}=s_k-z_k^2$, you could repeat by finding the conditional distribution of $Z_{k-1}$ given $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} Z_i^2 = s_{k-1}$ and so on